# Nav.xhtml for epub in Sigil - Insert blank space

Tags: css, xhtml

Thanks, everyone, for these tips and feedback.

In the ebook nav.xhtml, below is the code I'm dealing with.
I would like to have a blank space between the Preface and Part One of the book. However, any code I try to add to create a blank space or line does not work. Thoughts? Thanks, Dave

```
<h1>CONTENTS</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="../Text/Section0008.xhtml#preface">Preface (Adam Davis)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="../Text/Section0009.xhtml#one_part">ONE: BEYOND THE IMAGE</a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: Hello Dave. Please include the `nav,xhtml` and the relevant parts of your content files in your question. If you have some CSS written already, please also include that.

Comment: Hi I updated your question. Everyone appreciate assistance, you don't need to write that. And there is profile info next to every question, you don't need to write your name in question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Sigil, but since your tags include [css], I'm assuming you can change the css for this HTML. Then a possible answer could be

```css
li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <a href="../Text/Section0008.xhtml#preface">Preface (Adam Davis)</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="../Text/Section0009.xhtml#one_part">ONE: BEYOND THE IMAGE</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

But if you can't just change the CSS, but only the HTML, then you'll have to insert `<br>` elements in the list items.

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <a href="../Text/Section0008.xhtml#preface">Preface (Adam Davis)</a><br/>
    <br/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="../Text/Section0009.xhtml#one_part">ONE: BEYOND THE IMAGE</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

(Note that you need two `<br>`s to have an effect, since one `<br>` at the end of a block will be mostly invisible.)

By the way, you mentioned that adding br elements results in parsing errors, so I'm not sure what went wrong there. Is that something Sigil does? If so, this answer may be useless. Like I said, not familiar with Sigil, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Lister. Yes, I can work in the CSS, and your suggestion is solid--it allows spacing between all line elements. What I need is essentially an extra blank space, an extra return between certain line elements: between "Part Sections I, II, and III" in the Table of Contents. And yes, the br is not allowed with Sigil, creating the parsing error. 

Can I add a second type of line style or class so that in those three instances, I can apply the style/class to create a blank line? 

Thanks much,
Dave

Comment: If you mean you want to insert blank lines not between all elements, but only between some of them, then you need some way to tell the CSS what the difference is, i.e. the `li` elements that need blank space before or after them, need to be different from the other ones in some way. If not, then inserting `<br/>` in the right places would be the way to go, but if that is not accepted by Sigil, I don't know what to do. You will have to find someone more familiar with Sigil.